# How to display the saved state of a button when the page opens?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have three buttons. The maximum that I can select (activate) is only one button. When switching buttons, I have activated should be true, and not activated - false. I write these values ​​to SharedPreferences for each button, store true or false. When I open the pages all the buttons are gray out (they are not selected). I need to save the button state that it was selected and display it when the page is opened. For example, I just need if the variable isVoltageAC = true, then the AC button will immediately turn purple when the page is opened. How to do it?

```
enum VoltageMode {
  ac,
  dc,
  all,
}
class FilterDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  const FilterDialog({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FilterDialog> createState() => _FilterDialogState();
}

class _FilterDialogState extends State<FilterDialog> {
  VoltageMode? selectedMode;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<MapPreferencesCubit, MapPreferencesState>(
      builder: (context, statePreferences) {
        final MapPreferencesCubit mapPreferencesCubit =
            BlocProvider.of<MapPreferencesCubit>(context);
        if (statePreferences is MapPreferencesInitial) {
          mapPreferencesCubit.getPreferences();
        }

        if (statePreferences is MapPreferencesLoaded) {
          return BlocBuilder<MapfilterCubit, MapFilterState>(
            builder: (context, stateFilter) {
              final MapfilterCubit mapFilterCubit =
                  BlocProvider.of<MapfilterCubit>(context);
              if (stateFilter is MapFilterInitial) {
                mapFilterCubit.getFilter();
              }
if (stateFilter is MapFilterLoaded) {
                bool isVoltageAC = stateFilter.mapFilter.voltagePowerAC;
                bool isVoltageDC = stateFilter.mapFilter.voltagePowerDC;
                bool isVoltageAll = stateFilter.mapFilter.voltagePowerAll;
                return SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Dialog(
                    insetPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: 121, left: 24, right: 24, bottom: 60),
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        color: constants.Colors.greyDark,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(24)),
                      ),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 26, 0, 24),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [,
                            Padding(
                              padding:
                                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 21),
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  GestureDetector(
                                    onTap: () => setState(() {
                                      selectedMode = VoltageMode.ac;
                                    }),
                                    child: _buttonVoltage(
                                        'AC', selectedMode == VoltageMode.ac),
                                  ),
                                  const SizedBox(width: 16),
                                  GestureDetector(
                                    onTap: () => setState(() {
                                      selectedMode = VoltageMode.dc
                                    }),
                                    child: _buttonVoltage(
                                        'DC', selectedMode == VoltageMode.dc),
                                  ),
                                  const SizedBox(width: 16),
                                  GestureDetector(
                                    onTap: () => setState(() {
                                      selectedMode = VoltageMode.all;
                                    }),
                                    child: _buttonVoltage(
                                        'All', selectedMode == VoltageMode.all),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding:
                                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 21),
                              child: DefaultButtonGlow(
                                  text: 'Done',
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    Navigator.pop(context);;
                                    mapFilterCubit
                                        .setFilter(
                                      MapFilter(
                                        voltagePowerAC:
                                            selectedMode == VoltageMode.ac,
                                        voltagePowerDC:
                                            selectedMode == VoltageMode.dc,
                                        voltagePowerAll:
                                            selectedMode == VoltageMode.all,
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  },
                            ),

Widget _buttonVoltage(String nameButton, bool isActive) => Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 11),
        height: 40,
        width: 87,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: isActive
              ? constants.Colors.purpleMain
              : constants.Colors.white.withOpacity(0.15),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          border: Border.all(
            color: isActive ? Colors.transparent : constants.Colors.greyDark,
          ),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
                color: isActive
                    ? constants.Colors.purpleMain.withOpacity(0.34)
                    : Colors.transparent,
                blurRadius: 10,
                spreadRadius: 2,
                offset: const Offset(0.0, 1.0)),
          ],
        ),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child:
            Text(nameButton, style: constants.Styles.smallBoldTextStyleWhite),
      );
```

**cubit**

```
Future setFilter(MapFilter mapFilter) async {
    await _repository.setFilter(mapFilter: mapFilter);
    final MapFilter? filter = await _repository.getFilter();
    emit(MapFilterLoaded(filter!));
    return filter;}
```

**sharedpreferences**

```
Future setFilter({required MapFilter mapFilter}) async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString(_filterName, jsonEncode(mapFilter.toJson()));
  }
```

Comment: Can you include how you are saving it

Comment: My value is saved. But I don't know how to display it on the button that this particular button was selected

Comment: It is necessary to know how and what key you are using on saving

Comment: I added the code how to save

Answer (score 1):

you can read this values from SharedPreferences in initState of page. In this way your default value is ready when page loaded.

then make everything after SingleChildScrollView in separate widget like this:

```
Widget _buildBody(){
return SingleChildScrollView(
     child: Dialog(
       ...
      ),
   );
}
```

and pass this widget in your bloc builder after all if statement by default.

then do this:

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var result = prefs.readData(_filterName);
    if (result != null) {
        MapFilter mapFilter = jsonDecode(mapFilter.fromJson(result));
        if (mapFilter.voltagePowerAC){
          selectedMode = VoltageMode.ac;
        }else if (mapFilter.voltagePowerDC){
           selectedMode = VoltageMode.dc;
        } else {
          selectedMode = VoltageMode.all;
        }

      }
```

}

Comment: My value is saved. But I don't know how to display it on the button that this particular button was selected

Comment: could you please show me how save that value in sharedPref so I can tell you how to read it?

Comment: I added the code how to save

Comment: I update my answer

Comment: And how can I display the button as active after receiving this data?

Comment: for that you should show me the MapFilter model

Comment: My values ​​are correct. For example, I just need if the variable isVoltageAC = true, then the AC button will immediately turn purple when the page is opened.

Comment: I update my answer

Comment: Could you show me how to pass these variables to child: _buttonVoltage and then they can change?

Comment: I read you code again and realize that you did not need those variables. I update my answer again

Comment: I tried your method but did something wrong. I added my complete code, you could see how I originally received the data

Comment: The problem now is that I get the data the selected button is displayed, but now I can’t change it to another button